# shell function that takes directory name as it's parameter and checks whether the directory already exists

Tags: linux, bash, function

I want to pass directory name as the function's parameter and then check whether it exists or not. Here's what I got:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_function()   {
        dir="$1"
        if [ -d dir ]; then
                cd dir
        else
                mkdir dir
        fi
}
```

Comment: Now you can call your function in your script like so: `my_function "$1"` and call your script with `my_script SOMEDIR` (after doing `chmod 700 my_script`).

Comment: Of course there's a bit of circumlocution going on there, but you are doing fine this way.

Comment: You need to use `$` before `die` and double quote them.

Comment: Ah yes, I overlooked those, thanks @choroba.

Comment: What @choroba means is these occurences of dir: `-d "$dir"`, `cd "$dir"` and `mkdir "$dir"`.

Comment: so if you want to create the directory and `cd` to the directory you have to call your function twice?  or do you want to `cd` to the directory after `mkdir`? and if that's the case then perhaps simplify by replacing the `if/then/fi` with `mkdir -p "${dir}"; cd "${dir}"` or `mkdir -p "$1"; cd "$1"` ... making sure to use double quotes around the variable references in case the directory name includes white space

Comment: @markp-fuso will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to expand variables (parameters) in the shell is to stick a `$` in front of the variable name. `dir` is a constant string, `$dir` (or `${dir}`) expands to the contents of the variable. To deal with whitespace in the value, you should use the expansion only inside double-quotes, so,

```
if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
    mkdir -- "$dir"
```

etc.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters
and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting.